# How to groupby by multiple based on multiple column values?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

How can I group by three columns?

```
#df2 = df1.groupby(['TNVED',  'Year', 'Region'], as_index = False)
```

I am trying this code, but it's returning me 6 times fewer row numbers. I just want to group with any sum, mean etc.

the initial number of rows is 1771197
after the above-mentioned code = 338421

I have following columns:

```
Index(['TNVED', 'Product_Name', 'Export_Value', 'Import_Value', 'Year',
       'Country', 'Region'],
```

[image: Imagine that this is an initial data. Here data grouped by TNVED, Region and Year.]

this is a neww data.

```
  TNVED  Year Country               Region  Export_Value  Import_Value
0   010110  2011     AIA           Жамбылская           0.0       2.38398
1   010110  2011     AIA  РеспубликаКазахстан           0.0       2.38398
2   010110  2011     DEU          Актюбинская           0.0       4.26300
3   010110  2011     DEU           Жамбылская           0.0       5.95995
4   010110  2011     DEU  РеспубликаКазахстан           0.0      36.36281
5   010110  2011     DEU             г.Алматы           0.0      26.13986
6   010110  2011     FRA          Актюбинская           0.0       1.85800
7   010110  2011     FRA          Алматинская           0.0      42.70803
8   010110  2011     FRA  РеспубликаКазахстан           0.0      85.99814
9   010110  2011     FRA             г.Алматы           0.0      41.43211
10  010110  2011     GBR          Актюбинская           0.0      20.00000
11  010110  2011     GBR  РеспубликаКазахстан           0.0      27.49773
12  010110  2011     GBR             г.Алматы           0.0       7.49773
13  010110  2011     HUN           Жамбылская           0.0       2.38398
14  010110  2011     HUN  РеспубликаКазахстан           0.0       2.38398
15  010110  2011     IRL          Актюбинская           0.0      10.00000
16  010110  2011     IRL  РеспубликаКазахстан           0.0      36.30785
17  010110  2011     IRL             г.Алматы           0.0      26.30785
18  010110  2011     ISR          Актюбинская           0.0       1.47668
19  010110  2011     ISR  РеспубликаКазахстан           0.0       1.47668
20  010110  2011     ITA          Актюбинская           0.0      40.00000
21  010110  2011     ITA           Жамбылская           0.0      12.19392
22  010110  2011     ITA  РеспубликаКазахстан           0.0      52.19392
23  010110  2011     NLD  РеспубликаКазахстан           0.0      19.86249
24  010110  2011     NLD             г.Алматы           0.0       8.59547
```

As you can see, this data is grouped by TNVED and year, but I want grouped by TNVED, year, and Region. I do now want to any sum, mean etc

Comment: Sample data and sample answer would bring help quicker

Comment: Thanks, can you put a non image of the sample data like you have done with the sample answer

Answer (score 0):

Sample data would be helpful.

I would try `groupby()`, `.agg()`

```
  df1.groupby(['TNVED',  'Year', 'Region']).agg(Export_Value=('Export_Value','mean'),Import_Value=('Import_Value','mean'))
```